# Toggling the background color of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, input, toggle

I have this portion of code which is intended to changed the color of input button every time I click it.

```
function colorchange(id) 
 {
   if(document.getElementById(id).style.background == '#FFFFFF')
  {
   document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#000000';
  }
 else
  {
   document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#FFFFFF';
  }
 }

<input type="button" id="k777" onclick="colorchange('k777');" style="background:#000000;"/>
```

However this does not work properly.
It does change the color of the button from #000000 to #FFFFFF the first time I click it, but when I click it again it does not change back to #000000. It's still white.
How do I fix this?

Comment: try to alert the `document.getElementById(id).style.background`. You will see that there does not stand `'#ffffff'` ;-)

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById(id).style.background;
alert(x);`

Comment: Sidenote: Element id should always start with a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `element.style.background` returns values in the `rgb` format. Change your conditional `if` statement to check for the appropriate `rgb` values, and it should work fine.

Make that line this:

```
if(document.getElementById(id).style.background !== 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
```

[Demo, with your code fixed and cleaned up](http://jsfiddle.net/RhpAq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve it via css-classes

Here the HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.bg_1{
        background-color: #000";
    }
    input.bg_2{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<input type="button" id="input_777" onclick="colorchange('input_777');" class="bg_1" value="hello world" />
```

the JS:

```
function colorchange(id){
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    if(item.getAttribute('className') == 'bg_1'){
        item.setAttribute('className', 'bg_2');
    } else {
        item.setAttribute('className', 'bg_1');
    }
}
```

Maybe the Attribute is `class` in some browsers. You will have to check this. Btw. The code is not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorchange(id) 
 {

     var background = document.getElementById(id).style.background;

     if(background === "rgb(255,255,255)")
     {
     document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(0,0,0)";
     }
     else
     {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(255,255,255)"; 
     }

 }
```

Because its RGB values,

Its working here http://jsfiddle.net/nE8SW/
​

Comment: This won't work. Your `if` statement has it wrong. Change that to `==` or `===`.